# Escape characters in JSON string before ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON string

```
var str = '{'+
            '"name": "John Doe",'+
            '"company": [{"name": "ABC Corp"}, {"name": "XYZ Corp"}],'+
            '"salary": "$200000"'+
           '}';
```

I make the ajax call as

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'url',
     type: 'POST',
     context: document.body,
     dataType: 'json',
     data: str,
     success: function(data){},
     error: function(error){}
     });
```

How can I escape the double quotes inside the JSON array before making the ajax call.

Comment: And where exactly are you using this `str` variable ?

Comment: `escape(str);` will definitely escape everything

Comment: Why would you want to escape those quotes, since they're exactly as they should be?

Comment: Oh, so now the issue is apparent, you're stringifying a string, and that gives you an error. Just stop stringifying it, and why would you have a string to begin with, $.ajax accepts objects.

Answer (score 2):

`str` is already valid JSON (according to JSONLint), so you don't need to escape anything before sending it via `$.ajax`.

Comment: wait - so for the data option - you can just pass in a string like "test"?  I thought it had to be key/value like `"key=test"(as string)` or `{key:test} <-- as object`

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ - You can send a string formatted as json to `$.ajax`. You probably shouldn't but thats a different discussion.

Comment: @Jamiec hmm.. never knew that - will have to check out the code

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're going the wrong way - `JSON.stringify` is used to turn a JSON object to a string, the method you want is [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

So change that to:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'url',
     type: 'POST',
     context: document.body,
     dataType: 'json',
     data: JSON.parse(str),
     success: function(data){},
     error: function(error){}
     });
```

You can also pass a string formatted as JSON to $.ajax and as your string was already valid JSON you could just skip that step entirely:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'url',
     type: 'POST',
     context: document.body,
     dataType: 'json',
     data: str,
     success: function(data){},
     error: function(error){}
     });
```

Although you could just build it up as an object to start with if that is easier (It often is than trying to format a string!):

```
var postData = {
   name:'John Doe'
   ... etc
};

$.ajax({
     url: 'url',
     type: 'POST',
     context: document.body,
     dataType: 'json',
     data: postData,
     success: function(data){},
     error: function(error){}
     });
```

Comment: Why would you parse it if it's a valid string, you can't send an object so jQuery would have to stringify it back again internally ?

Comment: @adeneo - Im just answering the question as stated. I was updating with a better solution when you made that comment.

Comment: You should note that passing a JSON string will gives a completely different result than passing a JavaScript object.